# Android app and website(server) connection

Tags: android, visual-studio, ms-access, jsp

I want to create a browser to view as an administration.

My project is about ferry booking using an android phone. The application is connected to the server. The ferry timing and other info are retrieved via server connection. The database is currently in Microsoft Access.

**My question** is how do I create a browser to view data (e.g view users, delete users, create notification etc etc)? I want to create so called a 'website' that have access to the same database as the android application. Do I use Microsoft Visual Studio? How am I suppose to create a connection to Microsoft Access so that I can edit the database appropriately?

Thank you. I hope to have replies soon.

-Dayne

Comment: you mean inside an app i.e. you don't want to use android native browser for that.

Comment: Im not using android phone to view the browser. I just want to create a browser to view the database edit stuff using a computer/destop/laptop. You know what I mean.

Comment: outside the app. (android app)<------>server<------>(browser)

Comment: you can load your result into the web view...

Answer (score 0):

You're not entirely clear as to where the current application exists, you hint that either the data is inside of an access database, or are you have an existing application written in access.

In most cases a simple solution is to migrate the data out of your access application into a server based system.  The database server you choose should likely be one that your web hosting provider supports.  So SQL server or MySQL are often two good choices here.

You can continue to use your access application and have linked tables to that backend database server. (a good many web providers allow this). So, that sql server will presumably reside alongside your web server.  This setup will allow you to CONTINUE to use your existing Access application without having to rewrite it.  You then simply build some web pages in your favorite web development language to display the "dashboard" of informaton you need.

What tools you build the web site with are as varied as how many different kinds of ice cream there are. So, yes, this can be done with visual studio and asp.net pages, or virtually any web development system you choose. About the only requirement here is to ensure that your web hosting provider supports the deveopment tools you choose.

Depending on your current IT infrastructure, keep in mind that Access 2010 is capable of building 100% web based systems. However this ability in access 2010 does require sharepoint enterprise edition.

Comment: I beg to differ with your "a good many web providers allow this" -- my experience is that opening a database port to the Internet or setting up a VPN is a relatively expensive add-on for most low-level hosting packages (the ones that cost $10-20/month or less). It's also not something I'd recommend with an Access front end, as it's going to be pretty slow unless you work very hard to architect your data retrieval for WAN speeds.

Comment: Dotster allows this. Their plans start at $5.75 per month for 10 MySql databases. If you jump up to the next big and better plan at $8.75, then you get 25 databases. So, for less then $10, you have 25 separate connections. check out:

http://www.dotster.com/hosting/linux.php

Click on the more features in above, you see remote database is supported. I find quite a few support remote database these days.